# Strip list of sensitive query string values, also encoded, with regex

Tags: java, regex

**What I am trying to achive**

I would like to get replaced all the request parameters values which name is `password, secret, token` or so. Also should be replaced encoded values like `password%3D%22test%22` which is `password%3D%22test%22`.

**Here is my current regex**

```
((authtoken|api_secret|token|password|secret|\bkey\b|private\-?_?key|pswd?)(=|%3D%22))([^&|\"|%22]*)(%22)?
```

**Current implementation**

The current implementation partially works a part of the last usecase where the request parameter contains encoded `xml`. The issue is that the value matches only up to first occurrence of `2`. Used substitution is `"$1[PROTECTED]$5"`

[image]

**Question**

How can be the regex changed to consider whole sequence `%22` in the negate set?

**Expected result**

```
for=bar  =>   for=bar
password=value  =>   password=[PROTECTED]
?password=value  =>   ?password=[PROTECTED]
?password=value&  =>   ?password=[PROTECTED]&
?password=value&password=value  =>   ?password=[PROTECTED]&password=[PROTECTED]
foo=bar&password=value&foo=bar  =>   foo=bar&password=[PROTECTED]&foo=bar
{"url":"https://www.host.com/p?password=myKey&password=mySecret","b":"a"}}  =>   {"url":"https://www.host.com/p?password=[PROTECTED]&password=[PROTECTED]","b":"a"}}
https://host?api_key={$your_key}&password={$your_secret}&password={$your_secret}&a=b  =>   https://host?api_key={$your_key}&password=[PROTECTED]&password=[PROTECTED]&a=b
https://host?&password=xyz  =>   https://host?&password=[PROTECTED]
https://host:post?password=xyz  =>   https://host:post?password=[PROTECTED]
http://host:post?password=xyz  =>   http://host:post?password=[PROTECTED]
http://host:post?&password=xyz  =>   http://host:post?&password=[PROTECTED]
http://host:post?password=xyz&  =>   http://host:post?password=[PROTECTED]&
http://host:post?a=b&password=xyz  =>   http://host:post?a=b&password=[PROTECTED]
http://host:post?a=b  =>   http://host:post?a=b
http://host:post?password=xyz&a=b#hash  =>   http://host:post?password=[PROTECTED]&a=b#hash
http://host?foo=bar&xml=%3C%3Fxml+id%3D%220abc987%22+password%3D%22secreT12345%22+binds%3D%222%22  =>   http://host?foo=bar&xml=%3C%3Fxml+id%3D%220abc987%22+password%3D%22[PROTECTED]%22+binds%3D%222%22
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted, could you please at least provide an explanation why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[...]` is a character class. It matches a single character that is in the set `...` (or, with `[^...]`, a single character not in the set `...`).

`[^&|\"|%22]` is equivalent to `[^2&"%|]`

It's better to handle the two cases separately:

```
...(=[^&"\s]*|%3D%22[^"\s]*?%22)
```

To get the replacement working correctly, you can do this:

```
(...words...)(?:(=)[^&"\s]*|(%3D%22)[^"\s]*?(%22))
```

and replace by

```
$1$2$3[PROTECTED]$4
```

Comment: @PeterJurkovic It does if you copy/paste correctly: http://regexr.com/3gtes

Comment: Sorry about that. Still it is not what I expected http://regexr.com/3gtev

Comment: @PeterJurkovic Added `\s` to exclude whitespace from the pattern: http://regexr.com/3gtf2

Comment: Thank you, looks better, but for replacements till does not work. For example `?password=value&password=value => ?password=value$3[PROTECTED]$4&`

Comment: @PeterJurkovic It says `?password=[PROTECTED]&password=[PROTECTED]` here. Are we looking at the same page?

Answer (score 0):

Replace (whitespace added for readability)

```
(
  (authtoken|api_secret|token|password|secret|\bkey\b|private\-?_?key|pswd?)
  (=|%3D)
  (%22.*?%22 | \".*?\" | [^&]*)
)
```

with

```
$2=[PROTECTED]
```

Where %3D is `=`, and %22 is `"`.